# Assign looped records to single variable using php

Tags: php

I need to get all looped records to single variable. I tried this but i got final records of loop. How do i get all records. Can you please solve this. Here i added my code,

```
$text = '';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = 'column_value'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $text = '<li><div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h5>
                                <strong><a href="'.$row['field1'].'.php" class="post-title">'.$row['field2'].'</a></strong></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row post-content">

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p style="margin-bottom:0px">

';
$text.= substr($row['field3'],0,150);



                            $text.= '...</p>

                                <a class="pull-right" href="'.$row['field2'].'.php">>> Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></li>';
    }
```

Comment: If you're just going to echo it directly afterwards anyway, you might as well just output it as raw HTML. But your problem is that you're overwriting the `$text` variable each iteration, with `$text = '<li>...` instead of concating it, `$text .= '<li>...`

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use MySQLi / PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not concating your `$text` variable

```
$text = '';
while() { ...
  $text .= '<li>...'; // you missed this dot
}
echo $text;
```